# Archivos de texto en Python, librería IO o no usar librería?

Tags: python

quisiera postular la siguiente duda para todos ustedes, y si pudieran explicarme para entender mejor sería de mucha ayuda.

He visto dos formas para crear archivos en python y utilizarlos, la primera forma es importar la libreria io, ejemplo:

```
from io import open
archivo = open("archivo.txt","r")
lectura = archivo.read()
archivo.close()
print(lectura)
```

La segunda forma es de la siguiente manera, ejemplo:

```
archivo_1 = open("datos.txt","w") 
archivo_1.write("Primera línea. \n")
archivo_1.write("Segunda línea. \n")
archivo_1.write("Tercera línea. \n")
archivo_1.close()
```

Mi duda es: ¿Cuál es la diferencia entre hacerlo importarlo, y sin importar la libreria?, hago esta pregunta para entender qué beneficios trae el importar la libreria, y por qué se puede hacer de estas dos formas.

Agradezco los aportes que puedan dejar, gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cito [la documentación del modulo io](https://docs.python.org/es/3.9/library/io.html#io.open):

> Esto es un alias para la función incorporada open().

Es decir io.open y open son la misma cosa.

Sinceramente, no se por que esa función existe en el modulo io. Yo en lo personal no la hubiera creado.